# Adding a resource folder in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I want to add a folder as a resource folder in an IntelliJ IDEA project  (Java).

In project settings - Modules - ProjectName_main, I put a folder as a resource folder. However I can't reach a file in the folder.

General paths are like below.

```
LocalProject
    | - src
         | - main
               | - java
               | - resources
```

and adding a folder, say, `/tmp/resources`

Suppose I put a tmp.txt and main.txt in the folders in `/tmp/resources` and `LocalProject/src/main/resources`, respectively, and have a class `Hoge`, `Hoge.class.getClass().getResourceAsStream("main.txt")` works but doesn't work on the other file.....

How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you running a Maven project?  You need to make sure those resource files make it to your classpath.

Comment: is moving `/tmp/resources` into your project `resources` not an option?

Comment: The project is governed by Gradle. and I realized that even if I  rebuild, files in the added resource folder will not move or be copied to a bin path which is loaded when I run Java.
@NoobEditor yes I temporarily do it thank you. but if there is another way... I would follow...

Comment: As far as I know, such folders must be under the main folder.
Maybe you can use symbolic link.

Answer (score 0):

I tried and it works.

In build.gradle :

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDir '/tmp/resources'
        }
    }
}
```

It is recognized by Intellij

[image]

I added an image in this folder, and it is included in the final jar .

EDIT : Add some pics to answer a comment

About seeing files under /tmp :

Well it depends of the view used to display the project.
The **production** is fine.

[image]

Other views are differents, like the **project** one : It displays everything.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I tried it. When you set /tmp/resoures in Gradle like you, did your IntelliJ try to make all file lists under /tmp, didn't it?

Comment: It depends of the project view. I edited my answer and add some pics.